# libgdx tiledmap flicker with Nearest filtering

Tags: camera, libgdx

I am having strange artifacts on a tiledmap while scrolling with the camera clamped on the player (who is a box2d-Body).

Before getting this issue i used the linear filter for the tiledmap which prevents those strange artifacts from happening but results in Texture bleeding (i loaded the tiledmap straight from a .tmx file without padding the tiles).

However now i am using the Nearest filter instead which gets rid of the bleeding but when scrolling the map (by walking the character with the cam clamped on him) it seams like a lot of pixel are flickering around. The flickering results can get better or worse depending on the cameras zoom value.
But when I use the "OrthoCamController" class from the libgdx-Utilities which allows to scroll the map by panning with the mouse/finger i don't get these artifacts at all.
I assume that the flickering might be caused by bad camera-position values received by the box2d-Body's position.
One more thing i should add here: The game instance runs in 1280*720 display mode while my gamecam renders only 800*480. Wen i change the gamecam's rendersolution to 1280*720 i don't get those artifacts but then the tiles are way too tiny.

Has anyone experienced this issue or knows how to fix that? :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with this, and found it was due to having too small a decimal value for the camera position.

I think what may be happening is some sort of rounding with certain tile columns/rows in the tilemap renderer.

I fixed this by rounding to a set accuracy, like so:

```
camera.position.x = Math.round(player.entity.getX() * scalePosition) / scalePosition;
```

Experiment with various values, but I got it working by using the tile size as the scalePosition value.

Comment: This worked for me, I cast my floats position to ints when feeding into the camera

Answer (score 1):

About tilesets, I posted a solution here: [Getting gaps between tiled textures with libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062224/getting-gaps-between-tiled-textures-with-libgdx/18647048#18647048)

I've been using that method with Tiled itself. You will have to adjust "margin" and "spacing" when importing tilesets in Tiled to get the effect working.

It's 100% working for me :)