# Why do I have lines going across my libgdx game using Tiled?

Tags: java, libgdx, lines, visual-glitch, tiled

I'm using LibGdx and Tiled and when moving around the screen, there are both horizontal and vertical lines appearing on the game. I can post any code you need, if necessary. How do I get these lines to stop?

[image: Still image of said lines]

Here's a gfycat gif of the lines:

http://gfycat.com/FastUnnaturalAmericanwirehair

**Edit:**

Here's a small bitbucket repository, as small as I could get it that has the same glitch in it:

https://bitbucket.org/Chemical_Studios/example-of-line-glitch/src/8eeb153ec02236d836763072611bd7aa55d38495/minimalExample/src/com/weebly/chemicalstudios/minEx/?at=master

Comment: Post a minimal working example if you can.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean or not, but this is the current game file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nmzfm75atnz5pfi/TinyWorld.jar

Comment: Try to make one of these:

http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is this good enough? I tried to keep it as minimal as possible while still replicating the error: https://bitbucket.org/Chemical_Studios/example-of-line-glitch/src/8eeb153ec02236d836763072611bd7aa55d38495?at=master

Comment: If you have a small example, post the relavant code in the question.

Comment: That's as small as I can get it. I'm not sure what part of the code is actually causing it, as far as I know it's from Tiled. I'm not sure what's causing the problem, at all, sorry

Comment: Ok, there's a very large set of issues that could be happening here, and I don't have too much LibGDX experiance. You have seem to have put some effort into this, so I'm going to grab your code and try to find the issue.

Comment: If you don't use scaling, see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908317/libgdx-tiledmap-bug-in-render/41251081#41251081

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because you need to add a padding to your tiles.

This is a pretty common problem and you are not the first to encounter it. Basically due to rounding errors when scaling and panning around, sometimes you will render the area "between" two tiles, which will result in nothing being rendered -> black background colour comes through.

You basically need to use some tools to add the padding to your tileset. In this [forum thread](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=11078&p=49842) I explained how to do it.

There is also one more questions regarding this topic on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062224/getting-gaps-between-tiled-textures-with-libgdx).

Comment: That forum has been closed now so here's a Web Archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20160715150127/http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=11078&p=49842

Answer (score 1):

When you have rounding errors you can always force the number to snap to the grid you want. In my case that looked like this:

```
gameCam.position.x = (float) Math.round(player.b2body.getPosition().x * 100f) / 100f;
```

Because I used a pixels-per-meter constant of 100f throughout the game, to scale everything

Comment: Same deal here. A 100 made me problems but 10 worked just fine: `position.x = Math.round(position.x * 10) / 10f;` `position.y = Math.round(position.y * 10) / 10f;`