# LibGDX GraphicBug TiledMap OrthographicCamera

Tags: java, libgdx, tile

i'm working on IT project and I meet one bug, that resists.

My Project is a 2D game in LibGDX, and I use TiledMap(logicial) for create the maps. And an OrthographicCamera for render the screen.

But when I'm running on the map (with the player), "lines" often appear (vertical or horizontal) like here :

[image]

And I can't figure out what is the problem, especially as it does not happen all the time.

If anyone can help me, it would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Do these lines show up only at the edges of tiles?

Comment: You probably have a bug with rounding numbers

Comment: You have to pack your tiles with padding to avoid this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144367/why-do-i-have-lines-going-across-my-libgdx-game-using-tiled

Comment: Yes I've that bug only on the edge of tiles :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx !!!
My solution (based on your comments) is to round (2.12546 => 2.12) the position of the camera and round (2.12546 => 2.1) the zoom of camera, and it is solved !! THX !

PS : Just, I don't know why, just if I put a zoom at 4.0, I can see a vertical ligne for all tiles around the player.. It's weird.

But for me is ok for now !! thx again :D